# Picture how mapAccumR works

Tags: haskell

Can you explain how exactly `mapAccumR` works, the kind of problems it solves,and how it's different from `foldr`. I have a hard time picturing how it works.

Comment: `mapAccumR` is like calling `map` and `foldr` at the same time. The return value is a pair of values where the left value has the output of `foldr`, and the right value has the output of `map`.

Comment: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:mapAccumR

Comment: @4castle I agree and disagree at the same time :-P In plain `map`, every element of the output depends only from the element of the input at the same index. In the list result of `mapAccumR`, it would also depend on the other elements at the "right " (tail) of the corresponding input element.

Comment: To be fair, @chi it doesn't **have** to depend on it, it just can. If you need to do a separate fold and a separate map at the same time on a list, you can totally do that with one of the `mapAccum` functions. For example, summing the lengths and exclaiming the words in a string: `mapAccumR (\sumLength item -> (sumLength + length item, item ++ "!")) 0 $ words "This is interesting"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a good question. I wish the documentation was a bit nicer around this. I recently had a use for them myself, so hopefully I can explain from the perspective of someone who also had some trouble understanding how they worked.

So, the type signature of `mapAccumR` is:

`Traversable t => (a -> b -> (a, c)) -> a -> t b -> (a, t c)`

Let's just assume the `Traversable` under question is a list because it's possibly a bit easier to understand that way, so specialising the types:

`(a -> b -> (a, c)) -> a -> [b] -> (a, [c])`

So, to explain this, `mapAccumR` is a function of three arguments (ignoring currying, as we do for easy explanation), and I'm going to annotate these arguments here:

```
mapAccumR :: (a -> b -> (a, c))             -> a                     -> [b]           -> (a, [c])
mapAccumR :: mappingAndAccumulationFunction -> initialAccumulatorValue -> listToMapOver -> resultantAccumulatorAndMappedListPair
```

Cool, so that clears things a **little** bit, but it's still a bit confusing, right. So what the heck does it do?

Well, it does an accumulating map: so let's say in the first step, what it does is take the `initialAccumulatorValue` and the first `b` from the `listToMapOver`, and passes those to the `mappingAndAccumulationFunction` function, which will do **something** with them and return two things: 1. a new value of type `a` and 2. a mapped value for later collection into the mapped list (see the type of `resultantAccumulatorAndMappedListPair`). These two values are paired, hence the return type of the `mappingAndAccumulationFunction` function as `(a, c)`.

In the second and subsequent steps, it takes this `(a, c)` pair from the last step, pulls the `c` out and remembers it by appending it to an internal list it's keeping track of until the end, and pulls the `a` out as the first argument to the next application of the `mappingAndAccumulationFunction` along with the next `b` value of the `listToMapOver`.

Once it runs out of `b` values from `listToMapOver`, it returns a pair which has the last value of `a` and a list whose contents are of type `c`.

So why the heck would you want this function? Example time!

```
annotateLeastFavourites items = snd (mapAccumR (\num item -> (num + 1, show num ++ ": " ++ item)) 1 items)

itemList = ["Geese","Monkeys","Chocolate","Chips"]

> annotateLeastFavourites itemList
["4: Geese","3: Monkeys","2: Chocolate","1: Chips"]
```

or, maybe this is a bit simpler to see what's going on:

```
> mapAccumR (\num item -> (num + 1, show num ++ ": " ++ item)) 1 ["Geese", "Monkeys", "Chocolate", "Chips"]
(5,["4: Geese","3: Monkeys","2: Chocolate","1: Chips"])
```

So we can see that it's a function that can give us a "cumulative value" along with our accumulating value anytime we need some information to pass along a map, for example, or if we want to build up a collection value (on the right) that also needs to have information passed along that changes with each step (the value on the left).

Maybe you want to get the max length of a list of items as you also annotate them with each item's length

```
> mapAccumR (\biggestSoFar item -> (max biggestSoFar (length item), (item, length item))) 0 ["Geese", "Monkeys", "Chocolate", "Chips"]
(9,[("Geese",5),("Monkeys",7),("Chocolate",9),("Chips",5)])
```

There are lots of possibilities here. Hopefully now it's clear why people say this is like a combination of `map` and `foldr`. If you happen to think geometrically as I do, I think of it as when you need to transform a collection of some kind, and you need to thread some changing thing through that collection as part of the transformation.

Hope this has helped give you an intuition and store the pattern in your mind for later when you recognise you might need it in the future :)

```
let (_, result) =
  mapAccumR 
    (\cumulativeLength item -> 
      let newLength = cumulativeLength + length item 
      in (newLength, take cumulativeLength (repeat ' ') ++ item)
    )
    0
    ["Geese", "Monkeys", "Chocolate", "Chips", "Dust", "Box"]
in mapM_ putStrLn $ reverse result

Box
   Dust
       Chips
            Chocolate
                     Monkeys
                            Geese
```

Sometimes, and depending on the shape of the computation you want, you'd want to use `mapAccumL` instead of `mapAccumR`, but you get the picture.

Also, note that it's defined for `Traversable` instances, not just lists, so it will work on all sorts of traversable containers and data structures such as Trees, Maps, Vectors, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some examples, generated using `Debug.SimpleReflect`.

Below, `f` is the same `f` you would use in a `foldr`, except the arguments have been flipped. Otherwise, there's no difference.

Instead `g` is similar to what you would use in a `map`, except `g x y` does not only depend on the current list element `y`, but also on the results of the former fold `x`.

```
> import Data.List
> import Debug.SimpleReflect
> mapAccumR (\x y -> (f x y, g x y)) a [] :: (Expr, [Expr])
(a,[])
> mapAccumR (\x y -> (f x y, g x y)) a [b] :: (Expr, [Expr])
(f a b,[g a b])
> mapAccumR (\x y -> (f x y, g x y)) a [b,c] :: (Expr, [Expr])
(f (f a c) b,[g (f a c) b,g a c])
> mapAccumR (\x y -> (f x y, g x y)) a [b,c,d] :: (Expr, [Expr])
(f (f (f a d) c) b,[g (f (f a d) c) b,g (f a d) c,g a d])
```

Here is a `foldr` with `f` having its arguments flipped, by comparison.

```
> foldr (\x y -> f y x) a [b,c,d]
f (f (f a d) c) b
```

(I have no idea about why `mapAccumR` chose the arguments of `f` in the flipped order compared to `foldr`.)